# What is the proper name for what [ordered] is in PowerShell 3.0?

Tags: powershell-3.0

In PowerShell, you can specify a type with square brackets like so:

```
PS C:\Users\zippy> [int]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

There are also built in type accelerators like [xml] which saves a few keystrokes when you wish to cast something to an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

```
PS C:\Users\zippy> [xml]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlDocument                              System.Xml.XmlNode
```

You can generate the list via one of the two commands:

- PS v2.0 `[type]::gettype("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Get`
- PS v3.0 `[psobject].assembly.gettype("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Get`

PowerShell 3.0 adds an operator called [ordered]. Its not a type alias though.

```
PS C:\Users\zippy> [ordered]
Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ [ordered]
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ordered:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

However, it can cast [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)s to [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)s.

```
PS C:\Users\zippy> ([ordered]@{}).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     OrderedDictionary                        System.Object
```

So my question is, if [ordered] is not a type accelerator, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `[ordered]` is a bit of an aberration. It's neither a type nor an accelerator. It only exists in the parser and is treated as a hint on how to create a hashtable (i.e. don't use hashtable, use ordereddictionary instead.) Think of it as a .net attribute, except it's not :D

Comment: actually, i would call it a type alias.

Comment: @TaylorGibb look in my question, and I prove its not a type alias by showing how to enumerate all type aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command :

```
Trace-Command -Name TypeConversion -Expression {([ordered]@{}).gettype()} -PSHost
```

Let me imagine that the interpreter try to match recursively type in loaded assemblies and finished to match OrderedDictionary, this is just a supposition.