# PowerShell script to return members of multiple security groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to return all members of multiple security groups using PowerShell. Handily, all of the groups start with the same letters.

I can return a list of all the relevant security groups using the following code:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like"ABC*"' | Select-Object Name
```

And I know I can return the membership list of a specific security group using the following code:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Security Group Name" -recursive | Select-Object Name
```

However, I can't seem to put them together, although I think what I'm after should look something like this (please feel free to correct me, that's why I'm here!):

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like"ABC*"' | Select-Object Name
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {Get-ADGroupMember -$Group -recursive | Select-Object Name
```

Any ideas on how to properly structure that would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care what groups the users were in, and just want a big ol' list of users - this does the job:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "AB*"}

$rtn = @(); ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $rtn += (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($Group.Name)" -Recursive)
}
```

Then the results:

```
$rtn | ft -autosize
```

Comment: Thanks, I made one small change just to return the name only, which made the script into the following:

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "TIG*"}

$rtn = @()
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $rtn += (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($Group.Name)" -Recursive | select-object name)
}

$rtn | ft'

This did return duplicates (since some people are in multiple groups), however for me this was fine as I just copied the results into Excel and removed duplicates.


Thanks very much,

Chris

Comment: Glad I could help.. As a side note, adding: `$rtn | select Name -unique | ft -autosize` when returning results would have eradicated the duplicates.

Comment: This is a little easier with the same results:
get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "AB*"} | get-ADGroupMember | ft -AutoSize
Good luck! :)

Answer (score 13):

This is cleaner and will put in a csv.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "**"} | select name -expandproperty name)


$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{
"Group Name" = ""
"Name" = ""
"Username" = ""
}



Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{

$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
{
$Record."Group Name" = $Group
$Record."Name" = $Member.name
$Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
$Table += $objrecord

}

}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Fantastic!  This also allows you to get the groupname into your CSV by using new PS objects.  Nice.

Comment: This worked for me after I removed [`[ordered]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10238698/1026) for PS2.0 (check your version with [$PSVersionTable.PSVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1026)), added `-Encoding UTF8` to the `Export-CSV` to handle non-ascii characters in names, and added `-recursive` to Get-ADGroupMember to list members of the nested groups (alternately you might want to add the `objectClass` attribute to the output to distinguish member groups from member users).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for this!q

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Group1" -recursive | Select-Object Name | Export-Csv c:\path\Groups.csv
```

I got this to work for me... I would assume that you could put "Group1, Group2, etc." or try a wildcard.
I did pre-load AD into PowerShell before hand:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Import-Module
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: The above link is titled "How to add Active Directory module in PowerShell in Windows 7"

Comment: You can *not* 'put "Group1, Group2, etc.': "Cannot find an object with identity: 'Group1, Group2'"

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a list of a single group, and the members of each group.

```
param
(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)]
    [String]$GroupName
)

import-module activedirectory

# optional, add a wild card..
# $groups = $groups + "*"

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like $GroupName} | Select-Object Name

ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
   {write-host " "
    write-host "$($group.name)"
    write-host "----------------------------"

    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($groupname) -recursive | Select-Object samaccountname

 }
write-host "Export Complete"
```

If you want the friendly name, or other details, add them to the end of the select-object query.

Comment: Hi user2883951, it works like a charm, however it doesn't display the Group name before it list the username each ?